# PHP - spl_autoload and namespaces - doesn't work with capital letters

Tags: php

I've set up a really basic autoloader in my `index.php` to grab a namespaced class within `hello.php`. My development environment is *Ubuntu 12.04*.

Why am I trying to do this? I'm trying to stick to the [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) and [PSR-2 coding standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md), that includes:

> Class names MUST be declared in StudlyCaps
>
> Namespaces are as /Vendor/Class (note: capitals)

The following is my structure and code *that works* ***before*** *making the changes* to capitals.

**Folder Structure**

```
- web
  -- index.php
  -- core
    --- hello.php
```

**Autoloader**

Within index.php, I have my autoloader:

```
set_include_path(__DIR__);
spl_autoload_extensions('.php,.class.php');
spl_autoload_register();
```

**Class File**

Within the core folder, I have hello.php

```
namespace core;

class hello {
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'Constructed!';
    }
}
```

**Code that works**

If I run `$obj = new \core\hello();` in my `index.php`, I get back "Constructed!". Great!

---

**That which doesn't work**

Renaming my core folder to 'Core' - note the uppercase C, and also the namespace in `hello.php` to `namespace Core;`.

Now let's try again with `$obj = new \Core\hello();`

`Fatal error: Class 'Core\hello' not found in ...`

So please tell me, why am I not able to use capital letters to keep inline with the PSR standards? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__)` is unnecessary; you can just use `__DIR__`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll amend...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you run your PHP code on a Linux platform, it's important to remember that Linux is case sensitive with filenames.

This affects autoloaders because they typically use the namespace and the class name when building the filename to load.

If the folder is named `core`, then the namespace must be `core`, with the same capitalisation. If you change it to `Core` in the namespace, then you must do the same to the folder name. (and as a result, all other `core` classes must be changed to `Core` at the same time).

On Windows, this doesn't happen because the Windows filesystem isn't case sensitive. This can cause confusion when code is tested and works on a local Windows-based dev system, and then breaks when it is copied to a Linux-based server.

[EDIT]

Okay, so I missed that you had changed the dirname as well. But nevertheless, I still think this is an issue of the filename/dirname case.

I note that you're calling `spl_autoload_register()` without any params. This means that the default `spl_autoload()` function will be used as the autoloader.

If you read [the documentation for `spl_autoload()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php), you'll note that it uses the *lowercased* version of the class and namespace.

In other words, using the default autoloader, your classes can be mixed case, but the folder structure and filenames must be all lower case.

So in fact, for you, you need to keep your filenames lower case.

I've personally experienced it the other way round, as per my original answer, where I had a fully lower case filename, and my mixed case class name was breaking when I moved from Windows dev box to Linux server. The reason my experience is different from yours is because I'm using a custom-written autoload function, which doesn't do an auto-lowercase conversion, so the case of my filenames has to match that of my classnames.

Comment: This doesn't help unfortunately - as already stated the *change has definitely been made* from `core` to `Core` in the object declaration, the folder name and the namespace in `hello.php`.

Comment: hm, Okay, I missed the bit about you chaning the directory as well. sorry. but hang on -- I think I've spotted the problem... I'll just edit the answer....

Comment: Ahh, I see. I saw the following in one of the comments on there: `spl_autoload_register(function($class) { return spl_autoload(str_replace('\\', '/', $class)); });` - any advances on that as it doesn't seem to work - to allow uppercases?

Comment: @Jimbo - no, if you want to keep your filename case the same as the classnames, I think you'll have to write your own autload function rather than using `spl_autoload()` at all. It doesn't have to be complex; mine is only a dozen lines or so. In fact, you could take the example autoloader code from [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md).

Comment: I thought as much - thank you for pointing this out though, it helped a lot and I'm sure it'll be useful to others in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have shown us some good ambiguity.Correct me if I am wrong.

According to the specification you have to use the lowercased name of the class (and namespace) being instantiated.(http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php)

But PSR tells us to use the capital letters. If you want to stick with PSR then we have to overwrite the default spl_autoload to our own.

Comment: Actually, the *best* tool for the job now is Composer. If you start using it, it literally sorts out all your namespaces for you and you only need to include `vendor/autoload.php` at the top of your file to have all your namespaces automatically resolved.

Comment: I got introduced with composer while working on Zend2 framework installation.It's a good tool indeed plus I also would like to explore under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having issues with this, why not make use of ucfirst() or strtolower() ?

So the code below would try all lowercase and also try first letter uppercase files

e.g: somename.class.php or Somename.class.php

The is_readable() checks first as to not display the php error for file not found.

```
spl_autoload_register(function($name) {

    if (is_readable(strtolower($name).'.class.php')) {
        require_once(strtolower($name).'.class.php');
    } 
    elseif (is_readable(ucfirst($name).'.class.php')) {
        require_once(ucfirst($name).'.class.php');
    }
});
```