# how include all classes by preg_match and autoload

Tags: php, preg-match, spl-autoload-register

This code works on the local system but does not work on my host. This code is written in the initialize.php file.

```
// -> All classes in directory
foreach (glob('classes/*.class.php') as $file) {
    require_once($file);
}


// Autoload class definitions
function my_autoload($class)
{
    if (preg_match('/\A\w+\Z/', $class)) {
        include('classes/' . $class . '.class.php');
    }
}
```

I have two folder (private and public) in the root path, and the classes are in the private folder, like this:

[image]

Comment: Is there a difference for the value `$class` on your host and local system? `\w+` matches word characters, perhaps on your host the string contains other characters as well.

Comment: Does not display anything in my host (no output).

Comment: Does not enter the if block.

Comment: Is the function `my_autoload` triggered? What is the value of `$class` when you log it?

Comment: I modified the question, in this case the "admin" class does not know.
class Admin extends DatabaseObject

In this case the first output $class in my_autoload is "DatabaseObject"

Comment: yes this function triggered.

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps this page is helpful about using capital letters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027486/php-spl-autoload-and-namespaces-doesnt-work-with-capital-letters/21395227

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. My class name is camel case, but not the filename. However, it worked properly on the local system!!!

Comment: include('classes/' . strtolower($class) . '.class.php');

Comment: It's explained in the linked question. When you ask Windows for a file called `DatabaseObject.php` it returns `databaseobject.php` if found. Linux doesn't because the file name does not match—if fact you could have *both* files.